# Simulate Windows menu item activation

Tags: windows, dll-injection

I am trying to shortcut the call to a procedure that is activated when clicking on a menu item.

I injected a DLL on the process that creates this window with the menu bar.

I used Spy++ from VisualStudio to obtain the Menu Identifier for this specific item (wid: 40003). Now I am calling

`CallWindowProcW(wndproc, hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 40003, 0);`

**However, the item procedure is not triggered.**
I cannot call the procedure directly because I do not know what it is. I just know that when I click this menu it activates it.

I have obtained `windproc` and `hwnd` doing the following inside my DLL:

```
 void Init()
 {
     DWORD procID = GetProcessId(GetCurrentProcess());
     EnumWindows(myCallback, procID);
 }

 BOOL CALLBACK myCallback(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
 {
     DWORD wndId;

     GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &wndId);
     if(wndId == (DWORD)lParam) //Found the right window handle
     {
         WNDPROC windowFunc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
         LRESULT result = CallWindowProcW(windowFunc, hWnd, WM_COMMAND, 40003, 0);
         return FALSE;
     }
     return TRUE;
  }
```

<s>**EDIT**: Have also tried SendMessageA, PostMessageA and DispatchMessageA and failed</s>

**EDIT2**: See answer below for working PostMessageA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified the problem. It comes in two steps:

**1. Use PostMessageA instead of CallWindowProc**

`PostMessageA(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, 40003, 0)` does the heavy lifting and calls the WindowProc on the desired window.

**2. Make sure that the Window is Top-Level**

I had ignored this before because the application window was visible and I thought it was top-level.

However, since I am executing `EnumWindows` on the `Init` procedure of my injected dll, my launcher process was still running and the window was child of my launcher.

I had to wait for the launcher to quit, and then called `EnumWindows` and `PostMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have made this a comment but do not have enough points to do so so this would have been a comment on the answer.

Simply put, the topmost window in a windows environment receives the RawInputThread (RIT).  The RIT automatically receives the mouse and keyboard messages and sends them to that window which is at the top of the Z order.   Having done a lot of this stuff in the distant past, if you ever need to take total control, a trick that can be done is to implement a top most window (z order) window which covers the whole screen, RIT will give it all messages, and you do what you want with them.

Back when I was doing this there was little to no documentation on  RIT but now you can find lots of documentation.  I found this on [MSDN Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543(v=vs.85).aspx), but it looks like they are making it more complicated than it really needs to be.  MSFT has done things over the years where they hide a topic, then clarify, then put the topic back into hiding.  duckduckgo shows numerous [hits](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22raw%20input%20thread%22&t=hk&ia=web)  and yielded a nice [gem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773/) google didn't find on its first page.